# How to use D3 raise/lower with shapes that were added to the svg at different times?

Tags: d3.js

I have created a scatterplot using D3.js where I've added both circles and squares. After mouse over on a shape, I'd like to lower the shape to let other shapes behind it appear raised. Right now, lower/raise do not work to show circles above the squares if I add squares after adding circles on my svg. Any advice? Thanks!

Comment: When you say "after mouse over", do you mean `mouseout`? If yes, you can simply access the element which registered the event and lower(). Like so: `on('mouseout', function() {d3.select(this).lower()})`

Comment: ^I am assuming you're using d3 v7

Comment: It will be much easier to help you if you could provide a working codepen or such.